# Cómo buscar atributos en nodos especificos evitando cierta condición en Xpath .Net?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Necesitaría obtener los atributos "Id" de los nodos que se encuentran en un nodo especifico("edit") dentro del nodo root del xml("entity") y que no sean del tipo "hiddenItem".

El xml es algo como esto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<entity  xmlns="urn:framework-config">

    <!--mucho codigo innecesario-->

  <edit>
    
    <hiddenItem id="54" label="estoy oculto" ...etc>
    
    <textItem id="103" label="Nombre" ...etc>
    
    <staticCombo id="108" label="Apellido" ...etc>
  
  </edit>
</entity>
```

Entonces en mi aplicación .net hago algo como esto:

```
public class Experimental
{

    public static void FillTable()
    {
        string baseFolderPath = "c:\\work\\Mi_Path";

        WriteLog(">>------------------Esta funcionando-----------------<<");

        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(baseFolderPath, "Mi_Archivo.crud.xml"))
        {

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(file);
            
            foreach (XmlNode nodo in doc.SelectNodes("//entity/edit"))
            {
               
                WriteLog(nodo.Value.ToString());
                WriteLog(nodo.Name.ToString());

            }

        }

        }
}
```

Ok, aqui viene lo extraño. Estoy usando el Xpath tester online pero muchas sintaxis no me están funcionando en .net.

Por ejemplo esto funciona:

```
XmlNode row in doc.SelectNodes("//@Id")
```

me escribe en el archivo todos los IDs, desafortunadamente tambien lee archivos de la parte de codigo no permitida (fuera del tag edit)

Cuando quiero seleccionar solo los nodos dentro del edit así `//entity/edit` no devuelve nada.

La sintaxis es correcta?

Answer (score 1):

Por la declaración

```
<entity  xmlns="urn:framework-config">
```

el elemento "entity" y todos los elementos contenidos pertenecen al espacio de nombres ("namespace" en inglés) `urn:framework-config`.

In XPath 1.0, per seleccionar elementos en un espacio de nombres una expression como "entity" no vale porque siempre selecciona a elementos de eso nombre que pertenecen a ningún espacio de nombres.

Hay dos opciones: con XPath 1.0 tienes que utilizar un prefijo atado al espacio de nombres e.g.

```
       string xml = @"<entity xmlns='urn:framework-config'><edit><foo id='foo1'/><bar id='bar1'/><baz id='baz1'/></edit></entity>";

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

        XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);

        namespaceManager.AddNamespace("my", xmlDoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);

        foreach (XmlAttribute id in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("my:entity/my:edit/*[not(self::my:foo)]/@id", namespaceManager))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(id.Value);
        }
```

Otra opción is utilizar XPath 2 o 3, para hacer eso necesitas utilizar un paquete de NuGet, para XPath 2 el de XPath2 , para XPath 3 Saxon HE.

Ejemplo utilizando XPath2 (`using Wmhelp.XPath2;`):

```
        namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);

        namespaceManager.AddNamespace("", xmlDoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);

        foreach (XmlElement el in xmlDoc.XPath2SelectNodes("entity/edit/*[not(self::foo)]", namespaceManager))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(el.Attributes["id"].Value);
        }
```

Si quieres trabajar con la versión más actual de XPath, 3.1, se puede hacerlo en el .NET framework utilizando Saxon HE .NET. Sin embargo, se recomienda utilizarlo con su proprio API y estructura de datos para representar, es decir, de no utilizar `System.Xml.XmlDocument` sino un documento creado por el `DocumentBuilder` de Saxon. Ejemplo es (`using Saxon.Api;`):

```
        Processor processor = new Processor();

        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = processor.NewDocumentBuilder();

        // solo para utilizar un documento from a .NET String
        docBuilder.BaseUri = new Uri("urn:from-string");

        XdmNode xdmDoc = docBuilder.Build(new StringReader(xml));

        XPathCompiler xpathCompiler = processor.NewXPathCompiler();

        xpathCompiler.DeclareNamespace("", xdmDoc.Children().First().NodeName.Uri);

        XPathSelector selector = xpathCompiler.Compile("entity/edit/(* except foo)/@id").Load();

        selector.ContextItem = xdmDoc;

        foreach (XdmNode id in selector)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(id.StringValue);
        }
```